# Docker jwilder/nginx-proxy location configuration

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I have 3 ( app-client,app-a, app-b )applications are running in jetty server and one NGINX load balancer ( app-lb). All (internal or external) requests are coming   to my application  through load balancer. Based on web context ( /app-a/ or /app-b/) name, LB will forward the request to the correct application. I have configured (location /app-a/ and location /app-b and location /app-client) in LB. app-a will call app-b and app-b will call app-a , app-client will be called from outside world, app-client will call app-a or app-b.

I have written Docker-composer for my application. To avoid circular dependency, I have used Docker net. it is working good.

If I scale up my application. LB doesn't know about this new application container.

I have gone though few tutorials and trying to use **jwilder/nginx-proxy** instead of NGINX. if I use that using VIRTUAL_HOST=app-name variable it is updating upstream in configuration file.But, My application is running based on location mapping for each container.if I don't specify, how request will go to correct container.

How to give location mapping in LB's default.conf file like below since this configuration updated by container dynamically **or** how to make internal call urls.

```
   location /app-a {
            proxy_pass http://app-a;
    }
   location /app-client {
            proxy_pass http://app-client;
    }


   location /app-b {
            proxy_pass http://app-b;
    }
Request from outside: http://IP:9090/app-client/
Internal call : http://app-lb:80/app-a/
                http://app-lb:80/app-b

   LB exposed port no is 9090
```

Answer (score 3):

There are pull requests [(e.g. #599)](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/pull/599) for the nginx-proxy image to support virtual paths. To implement this, you can use the original image and just pass your own nginx.tmpl file into the container (as a volume mount, e.g. -v `$(pwd)/nginx.tmpl:/app/nginx.tmpl:ro`). Then your containers just need to define `VIRTUAL_PATH` as they would `VIRTUAL_HOST`.

I'd also recommend setting `DEFAULT_HOST` on the nginx-proxy container and have everyone point to that if you don't want hostname based routing.

Note with #599, there's a bug in the nginx.tmpl that I ran into, you need to move `{{ $networks := .Networks }}` up two lines to be before the `{{ range $container := .Containers }}` (the range redefines `.` which redefines `.Networks`). Otherwise all networks will be assumed reachable and you'll get timeouts if the container is also attached to other networks that nginx-proxy can't reach.

Comment: I am planning to use dockercloud-haproxy. it has VIRTUAL PATH and HOST. please suggest me on this

Comment: The question above was for jwilder's nginx-proxy, which I've answered here. I don't have any advice for dockercloud-haproxy, that would be a different question.